# Google App Script ListBox - Reading items

Tags: listbox, google-apps-script

I can not find a way to read the items in a UI ListBox object. I have search and found some methods like getItemCount() and getItemText() in the Google Web Toolkit but they are not available when using the object in a javascript.....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the list-box widget trough a Server Side call to get the selected data out of it:

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var lb = app.createListBox();
  lb.setName("calName") //name used to fetch selected result
  .addItem("Text Option One", "1")//options for selection
  .addItem("Text Option Two","");//first peram display text and second peram value
  app.add(lb); // adds listbox to display
  app.add(app.createButton("Click Me")//create button
         .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("showResult") // Create server side execution to handel click
                          .addCallbackElement(lb))); // add list-boxas element to be passed to server as parameter
 return app;
}

function showResult(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var res = e.parameter.calName;//parameter name same as list-box name given 
  app.add(app.createLabel("Selected option is " + res));//displays selected option
  return app;
}
```

just create test app and save a version, Use this code for application and view latest code after deploying it.